# ¿ Como escribir en un archivo xlsx con pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

```py
for row in df['ClienteId']:
```

Requiero escribir en un ciclo un resultado, en la primera fila en la columna Prueba, cuando vuelva a recorrer el ciclo lo realice ya en la segunda fila tal cual se muestra en la imagen.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenid@ a SOes te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] para que sepas como funciona el sitio y también obtengas tu primera medalla! también lee [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Las imágenes mostrando código no son bien recibidas, por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/481844/edit) tu pregunta

Comment: Podrías colocar los datos de tu dataFrame? y el resultado que esperas

Comment: Disculpa bro no tengo la posibilidad en este momento de colocarlos.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Realice mi pregunta de manera diferente no se si me hago aclarar.

Comment: ok no te preocupes. Lo que quieres es escribir por filas verdad? lo que escribas será lo mismo para todos o cada uno tendrá un valor específico?

Comment: por cierto Comunidad es un bot, pero lo que se te dio es un mensaje realizado por otro usuario, siempre es bueno tener en cuenta los comentarios

Comment: @Christian Si Señor Requiero escribir por filas y tendrá un valor diferente

Comment: Claro que si lo tendré en cuenta muchas gracias por ayudarme!!

Comment: @Christian Agradezco mucho la ayuda que me puedas brindar. Soy nuevo usando StackOverFlow

Comment: Con los enlaces que te brindé podrás aprender un poco más. Por cierto ahora estoy escribiendo la respuesta, espera un poco

Comment: Vale muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

Existen diversas forma de realzar lo que quieres, yo te mostraré una que a mi parecer es mucho más fácil de entender y manejar. Empecemos por lo básico, un DataFrame es un tipo de dato creado por Pandas, los DataFrames se conforman por Series de pandas. Si por ejemplo nosotros tenemos un DataFrame cuyas columnas son los días de la semana, si hacemos `print(type(df["lunes"]))` se nos dirá que es una Serie, más específicamente veremos este resultado `pandas.core.series.Series`.

Los DataFrames se pueden elaborar de varias formas, podemos tener un diccionario `{key: value}` donde la `key` será el nombre de la columna y el `value` los datos que contendrá, o podemos hacer un DataFrame a partir de una matriz `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6], [7,8,9]]` donde cada lista corresponde a los datos de una fila, etc.

Para este caso voy a utilizar el concepto de Series para reemplazar una columna entera de un DataFrame dado que ya tienes un DataFrame creado y no perderé tiempo creando uno nuevamente.

He tratado de replicar un poco el escenario en el que nos encontramos, donde necesitamos rellenar los valores de una fila

```py
import pandas as pd

cols = ["ClienteId", "nombre"]
data = [
        [1,""],
        [2,""],
        [3,""]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= cols)
```

Si nosotros queremos reemplazar una columna tendremos que hacerlo con un dato del mismo tipo, es decir que igualmente sea una Serie de pandas. Para ello utilizaremos el método `pd.Series()` para crear una y le pasaremos como argumento una lista donde cada elemento representará una fila.

Para el caso anterior podríamos hacer:

```py
nombres = ["christian", "naokiri", "jose"] #lista de todos los nombres
nombres = pd.Series(nombres) #convertimos a una serie

#reemplazmos los valores de la columna nombre por nuestros valores
df["nombre"] = nombres
print(df)
```

Y obtendremos algo como esto:

|  | ClienteId | nombre |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | christian |
| 1 | 2 | naokiri |
| 2 | 3 | jose |

Pero que pasa si nostros tenemos más columnas y queremos reemplazar valores de más columnas, pues podemos hacer un ciclo `for` para ir seleccionando las columnas y tener una matriz de listas para ir reemplazando los valores. Por ejemplo teniendo este DataFrame:

```py
cols = ["ClienteId", "nombre", "edad"]
data = [
        [1,"",""],
        [2,"",""],
        [3,"",""]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= cols)
```

Tendríamos que crear una lista con las columnas a reemplazar y otra matriz con los valores

```py
columnas = ["nombre", "edad"]
datos = [
         ["christian", "naokiri", "jose"], #para la columna nombre
         [16,16,20] #para la columna edad
]

#recorremos las datos
for col, valor in zip(columnas,datos):
    df[col] = pd.Series(valor)

print(df)
```

La función `zip` lo que hace es mezclar ambos datos, es casi como un emparejamiento. Crea una tupla donde el primer valor de la variable columnas va con el primer valor de la variable `datos` y como nos devuelve una tupla de 2 elementos podemos separar esos elementos en variables distintas.

Eso nos da un resultado como este:

|  | ClienteId | nombre | edad |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | christian | 16 |
| 1 | 2 | naokiri | 16 |
| 2 | 3 | jose | 20 |

Si tienes alguna duda avísame y trataré de resolverla